# In python how to pass a variable to the command line?

Tags: python, variables, command-line, sys

I have a function that I use something like that:

```
def func(file_path):
    !python some_script.py --par file_path

func('/some/file/path/file.csv')
```

This obviously results in an error message, because Python assumes that `file_path` in the line `!python some_script.py --par file_path` is a literal file path, while I want to use it as a variable representing a file path.

So, how do I pass a variable into the command line `!python some_script.py --par file_path`? How do I tell the command line that `file_path` is not the path, but represents it? Tnx

Comment: You'd better use the subprocess module to start other processes. AFAIK the exclam. character is a non standard shortcut.

Comment: What you posted is actually not valid python, this is IPython "magic" specifically. You probably shouldn't use it for something like this, just use the `subprocess` module

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks, this worked! But when I use this `subprocess` package the print statements/output is not shown on the screen. How can I achieve this? And I want the output to be immediate, not when the complete process is done. Tnx

Comment: This depends on the exact syntax you are using... and that you do not show here! Look more carefully on the module doc. or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the value of your variable as an argument to a command line command, you can use string formatting or concatenation to construct the command, like so:

```python
import subprocess

def func(file_path):
    command = f"python some_script.py --par {file_path}"
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

func('/some/file/path/file.csv')
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not an **AI-generated** answer?

Comment: Another thing - when using this `subprocess` package the print statements/output is not shown on the screen. How can I achieve this? And I want the output to be immediate, not when the complete process is done. Tnx